# c++ std::map deleting pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, free

I will link the classes and output from execution below.

The problem is, the `std::map` is iterating through and the pointer stored in the second which is of type `void*` is not deleting from the heap and freeing. The `std::map` iterated through in the `void ShutDown(void);` method of the `class Engine` which is called in the `destructor` for that class.

I will post the code and output from execution.

Engine header file:

```
#ifndef _TEST_ENGINE_H_
#define _TEST_ENGINE_H_

#include "test_graphics_system.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace Core {
    enum class EngineStatus {
        Invalid,

        Constructing,
        Setup,

        Running,

        ShutDown,
        Destroying
    };

    class Engine
    {
    public:
        Engine(void);
        ~Engine(void);

        template<class T> T * GetSystem(SystemType systemType)
        {
            if (mSystems[systemType])
            {
                return (T*)mSystems[systemType];
            }
            else
            {
                std::wcout << "System doe not exist" << std::endl;
            }
            return nullptr;
        }

        int Run(void);

    private:
        template<class T> void AddSystem(T * system)
        {
            size_t count = mSystems.size();
            auto pair = std::make_pair(system->GetType(), (T*)system);
            mSystems.insert(pair);

            if (count == mSystems.size())
                std::wcout << "System failed to be added" << std::endl;
            else
                std::wcout << "System added" << std::endl;
        }

        void Setup(void);
        void ShutDown(void);

        void SetupGraphicsSystem(void);

        static EngineStatus mEngineStatus;

        std::map<SystemType, void*> mSystems;

        bool mRunning;
    };
}

#endif _TEST_ENGINE_H_
```

Engine source file:

```
#include "test_engine.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Core;

EngineStatus Engine::mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::Invalid;

Engine::Engine(void)
{
    mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::Constructing;

    Setup();
}

Engine::~Engine(void)
{
    mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::Destroying;

    ShutDown();
}

int Engine::Run(void)
{
    mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::Running;

    return 0;
}

void Engine::Setup(void)
{
    mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::Setup;
    SetupGraphicsSystem();
}

void Engine::ShutDown(void)
{
    mEngineStatus = EngineStatus::ShutDown;

    wcout << endl;
    int count = 0;
    size_t total = mSystems.size();
    for (auto obj : mSystems)
    {
        safe_delete(obj.second);
        wcout << "\rSystem(s) deleted: " << ++count << " of " << total;
    }
}

void Engine::SetupGraphicsSystem(void)
{
    GraphicsSystem * gs = new GraphicsSystem(mSystems.size(), L"GraphicsSystem01", SystemType::Graphics);
    AddSystem(gs);
}
```

Main source file:

```
#include "safe_del_rel.h"
#include "strings.h"

#include "test_engine.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Core;

void _DebugMemLeakDetection(void) {
#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
    int flag = _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    flag |= _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF; // Turn on leak-checking bit
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(flag);
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc(0);
#endif
}

int main(int argv, char argc[])
{
    _DebugMemLeakDetection();

    Engine * eng = new Engine();
    eng->Run();

    system("pause");
    safe_delete(eng);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from last runtime:

```
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\vs_projects\test_engine\x64\Debug\test_engine_console.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_engine_console.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x4134 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x46ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x307c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{161} normal block at 0x00000293DD5E2680, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <G r a p h i c s > 47 00 72 00 61 00 70 00 68 00 69 00 63 00 73 00 
{160} normal block at 0x00000293DD5E1820, 16 bytes long.
 Data: < R]             > A0 52 5D DD 93 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
The program '[12764] test_engine_console.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

If someone can help plesae do.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. removing some blank lines would be a start.

Comment: @AliceTurner Please stop writing `void` in parameter lists - simply leave them empty. Please stop using raw pointers. Please stop using `std::endl` when what you mean is `'\n'`. thanks.

Comment: What is `safe_delete`? Note there's no portable way to destroy the object a `void*` points to.

Comment: I think you want some kind of smart pointer to wrap void * and delete it properly. std::shared_ptr<void> perhaps?

Comment: If you store allocated values in a container that is responsible for freeing them, use `std::unique_ptr`, not a raw pointer.

Comment: Any time you have `void *` in a C++ program and it wasn't forced on you as a parameter for a callback function or other similar function you need to supply to a C-style API, you should stop and do a rethink from the point of view that you've made a mistake somewhere. Templates or inheritance should handle almost every other use of `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a `void *` pointer causes undefined behavior, most compilers will issue a warning about this. While the storage for the `GraphicsSystem` will be freed, its destructor will not be called.

Typically in C++ you would declare `std::map<SystemType, Base*> mSystems;` where `Base` is some class all your systems derive from, although mapping to smart pointers to `Base` is almost always a better idea. If this isn't possible (e.g. `GraphicsSystem` is an external class) then you could, for example, wrap it in a templated handle that derives from `Base`.

Comment: You're very likely right, but there's no way for us to know what's happening in `safe_delete`.

Comment: Very true, I went for a working assumption is that it's `if (p) { delete p; p = 0;}` like 99% of all `safe_delete`s.

Comment: I fail to see what so safe about that, but I'm sure someone will drop by and educate me if that actually does have merit.

Comment: I don't either but it's relatively harmless.

Comment: I think, the only way safe_delete could be safe is the case when the architecture is very rigid and underlying objects are something trivial, with common fixed header or with data that contain info on type and/or size. delete function would use it. I saw such but those always rise the question, why an OOP type erasure wasn't used instead. Usually because of some API was in use that required *void, e.g. sending over network socket.

Comment: Safe delete looks like this in code `#define safe_delete(x) delete x; x = nullptr;`. I will take the answer above in that c++ is freeing the memory but undefined behavior is happening. This is due to the fact in the memory tool the memory is showing as 0x00000000000 in the snap after running the `safe_delete` macro. It is only the output window after execution showing that the object i s not freed, this is standard code for me and this has never happened before ever.

Comment: One last add to solve the problem for peace of mind. I simply changed the storage container from `std::map<SystemType, void*> mSystems;` to `std::map<SystemType, System*> mSystems;`. Surely enough the out doesn't show any memory leaks now it knows the type

Comment: Make sure you're familiar with virtual destructors too.

Comment: @AliceTurner `delete`ing a `void *`is undefined. If the pointed at structure is simple, odds are good that the memory will be freed and handled as you'd expect, but if there are complex structures in there or special destruction requirements ([it's non-POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType)), then the compiler has no way of knowing that it should handle those special requirements. This be undefined behaviour, but some educated guesses can be made. 1/2

Comment: Consider an object like `std::vector`.  Without `vector`'s destructor running, nothing will free the `vector`'s underlying array or destroy the objects in the underlying array.  This would result in at least one and possibly N memory leaks. 2/2